# "permission" fields on a join table (relationship model) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relationships model that holds 2 user_ids, a follower_id and a followed_id

When a user "follows" another user a relationship record is added which includes these two id's.  I would like the followed user to have some say as to what the following user can see, so I am thinking of adding adding field(s) to the record, such as "followed_user_allows_follower_to_see_email_address" (it would be a less verbose)

This seems like the correct place to add these attributes, are there any reasons I should store these some place else?

Is there any reason I should not just store a list of permissions, rather than an attribute for each permission?  For example followed_user_allows_follower_to "see_email_address,see_some_other_detail,yet_another_detail"  vs  a separate field for each permission.